# Why do we use process when we do have threads?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Why do we use processes. Can't we build an environment where all things are done with threads.
Some reasons I might think are :

- A malacious blocking thread might cause all threads to block.
- Security problems with threads, as sharing may lead to more inconsistencies and more syncronizaton will be needed.

Apart from this, if their is no security issue , can we move to a totally threaded environment to work with?

Comment: Could you clarify, do you mean move an entire operating system to a single process threaded environment, or are talking about a specific application program? You ask "can we move to a totally threaded environment..." my question is move what? The entire OS or some specific software?

Comment: operating system is also a software that manages the hardware and other things. So I am just asking whether can we move our software(operating system) environment from a process specific model to a thread based model ? can we ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with moving to a totally threaded environment (that is, all processes are converted to threads sharing the same virtual address space) at the operating system level would be the lack of memory protection. I can't think of a rogue thread being able to halt the others, but it could certainly go poking around in memory places it's not allowed to go to. With protection violated, there would be alot of security issues. However, if all threads behaved well, it would work fine. It would be akin, however, to pre protected memory operating systems where one thread would crash the entire system.

That said, the advantages of such a system are negligible. In current systems, two processes can already request a segment of shared memory for cooperation (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)). The only other advantage I could think of would be that there would be potentially less overhead with context switching. In a very adventuresome environment one could even turn of virtual memory altogether and run every thread in kernel space, as in [the original xbox operating system](http://www.xbox-linux.org/wiki/17_Mistakes_Microsoft_Made_in_the_Xbox_Security_System) (Link appears broken, [alternative here](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2005/fahrplan/attachments/591-paper_xbox.pdf)). This would have the effect of faster execution all around, but even slight buffer overruns would potentially corrupt everything.

To conclude, there has been alot of research on operating system security with regard to processes and threads. The nature of both the encapsulation and independence of processes makes them well suited for concurrency. If they are not fast enough for you, write a single process with multiple threads for a specific user application, but it's best not to go back to the dark ages of pre-protective computing and clobber everything together in one memory space.

Answer (score 2):

if you mean "can we rewrite our multi-process based application to a single-process multi-thread app" then the answer is likely to be 'yes'.

If you mean "can I write an operating system that doesn't have processes anymore but only threads" then the answer is a resounding 'no'.  A thread has far too much access to program state.  Which makes them very efficient, but also very dangerous.  Failure is the problem, whether failure induced by a hard crash of the thread due to a processor fault.  Or a problem like deadlock.  Terminating the thread and having that have no affect on the state of the rest of the program is currently not possible.  A process provides the isolation boundary, allowing mis-behaving code to get terminated without affecting the stability of other processes running on the machine.  It also provides a privilege boundary that is very important for security.